# Java, Weka: NaiveBayesUpdateable: Cannot handle numeric class

Tags: java, weka, bayesian

I am trying to use NaiveBayesUpdateable classifier from Weka. My data contains both nominal and numeric attributes:

```
  @relation cars
  @attribute country {FR, UK, ...}
  @attribute city {London, Paris, ...}
  @attribute car_make {Toyota, BMW, ...}
  @attribute price numeric   %% car price 
  @attribute sales numeric   %% number of cars sold
```

I need to predict the number of sales (numeric!) based on other attributes. When I run:

```
    // Train classifier
    ArffLoader loader = new ArffLoader();
    loader.setFile(new File(trainFileName));
    Instances structure = loader.getStructure();
    structure.setClassIndex(structure.numAttributes() - 1);

    // train NaiveBayes
    NaiveBayesUpdateable nb = new NaiveBayesUpdateable();
    nb.setUseKernelEstimator(true);
    nb.buildClassifier(structure);
```

I get exception:

```
  Exception in thread "main" weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException: weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesUpdateable: Cannot handle numeric class!
      at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:954)
      at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1110)
      at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1023)
      at weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Capabilities.java:1302)
      at weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes.buildClassifier(NaiveBayes.java:213)
      at foo.bar.IncrementalClassifier.trainEvalPredict(IncrementalClassifier.java:65)
      at foo.bar.IncrementalClassifier.main(IncrementalClassifier.java:36)
```

How can I use numeric attribute for Bayes classification in Weka?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the Bayes classifiers in Weka for numeric predictions. None of them support this.

Comment: In case I split value of numeric attribute in `N` intervals of length `k` can I use instead nominal attribute, where `n` is a class name, like this: `@attribute class {1,2,3,...N}`? How big can be this `N` in Weka?

Comment: You can and it can be as big as you like really. Note that this is not recommended in this case though as you're clearly predicting a numeric quantity.

Comment: What algorithm would you recommend to predict numeric quality?

Comment: You can use any of the ones in Weka that are capable of doing this, e.g. REPTree or the SVMs.

Comment: As far as I understand SVM allows to classify data in two classes only. And I need to predict numeric value or range this value fits in. Also in case of range I am interested in minimal one that holds a true value. How is that possible with SVM?

Comment: I would recommend that you use the Weka GUI to explore what kind of algorithms you can use and predictions you can make with your data set.